# AWS CLI ECS Unknown options: --service-connect-defaults?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli

I am following the official AWS [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-service-connect.html) to create an ECS cluster with service connect and the docs say to create a cluster using `aws ecs create-cluster --cluster-name tutorial --service-connect-defaults namespace=service-connect` but i keep running into `Unknown options: --service-connect-defaults, namespace=service-connect`. I checked the AWS CLI docs and clearly see these options available there as well [link](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/create-cluster.html).

My environment is `aws-cli/2.7.27 Python/3.9.11 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off`.

What am i doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Run `aws ecs create-cluster help` to see what your installed version supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECS Service Connect is a fairly new feature. You are currently using the AWS CLI version `2.7.27`. The latest version as of today is `2.11.15`. You need to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: voila!!! Thank you and have a great weekend.